Landlord has broken lease agreement and not refunding the money
I signed a lease agreement for an apartment in Mississauga that is starting from 1st of May 2024. I paid the first and last month deposit directly to the landlord account. Yesterday the landlord sent me an audio message that he can’t give me the apartment neither he will return the money i gave him as first and last month. Which is $5000 Cad. I am a new immigrant. Please any suggestions what can i do now. My flight to toronto is in few hours.

We can't give legal advice here; try https://www.legalaid.on.ca/

This does need to be closed since it's requesting specific legal advice, but I think you've gotten some good starting points.

Consider the possibility that the "landlord" actually has no ownership rights to the property that you tried to lease and that they scammed you. See if you can find online the real owner of the property that you wanted to lease and compare the name and address to the person who took your money. Call them if possible.
If you have been scammed, you should file a police report.

You can sue him for breaking the agreement.
Document everything about it. The more evidence you have, the easier it will be.
